# Getting the HTML code of a chart created by chart.js

Tags: php, chart.js, dompdf

How can I get the HTML code of a chart created using chart.js and output it in a pdf with the use of dompdf load_html().

Answer (score 0):

In Charts.js you can use the method `.toBase64Image()` to convert the chart to a png.

It says it [in the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#tobase64image):

> ### .toBase64Image()
>
> This returns a base 64 encoded string of the chart in it's current state.

You can then pass that image to your dompdf library.